# XPath Expression to Return Nodes with Attributes of a Certain Length

Tags: xpath

I need to grab all nodes of particular type within an XML document but only if their *value* attribute is not empty. I've tried a few permutations on the below, but with no luck:

```
".//Foo[not([@Value =''])]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
//Foo[@Value!='']
```

Or if you really want to only return nodes with a value attribute of a certain length use something like:

```
//Foo[string-length(@Value) &gt; 3]
```

or

```
//Foo[string-length(@Value) = 0]
```